# Need advice converting my app to allow realtime updates

Tags: php, node.js, real-time

I have a web application that was built rather hastily to simply demo our idea to a select few people. It needed updated information, so I threw together our demo using a quick and dirty short-polling technique with jQuery and PHP. Performance did not matter as there would only be just a few people accessing this demo at any given time.

The application is basically a realtime queue that is fed items from an android application. Right now I have the android sending POST data to an API which adds a record to the database. I then use short-polling to keep the queue updated on the web side of things (not ideal, I know).

Now that the demo is over and there is significant interest, I am tasked with the idea that this app will have to be able to scale to my estimation of around 2500 clients connected at once every single day (500 stores w/ up to 5 browsers connected all the time), within the next year or so.

In order to make this a reality I have been reading on the various ways of making this application realtime as well as using long-polling techniques like Comet. My head is sort of spinning right now with all of the various options out there. I have looked at services like Pusher, but we are really trying to minimize monthly costs so that's really only a last resort option. Node.js seems like the popular option, but that would require me to rewrite my entire app, wouldn't it?

Even if I do use something like Node.js, I'm sort of lost on how I handle the incoming POST data from the android app and have it both update the database and send it to the clients browsers.

The real-time queue is only one part of the web application, and the rest can be done without needing any real-time functionality. If I go with node.js can I write just the queue in node.js and run the rest of the web site using a more traditional LAMP stack?

I do have the advantage of controlling what browsers are being used in the stores (Chrome), so I don't really need to worry about legacy browser support.

Really any advice that can steer me in the right direction would be greatly appreciated. It seems like there are tons of options out there, but I'm not sure which one is best for my situation.

Comment: Look into using web sockets instead of any sort of polling for the "real-time" data. Also, take a look at the pubsub pattern - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Publish%E2%80%93subscribe_pattern as what you're describing seems to fit the model.

Comment: Would a web socket solution like Ratchet scale well for what I am doing?

Comment: Probably, but you'll have to test to know for sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are right in saying that node.js lends itself better to reactive APIs and performing event-based procedures due to the asynchronous nature of Javascript.

However, that isn't to say you can't achieve the same effects in PHP. While I'm a node.js fan and advocate, it sounds like you've done a fair amount of work in your language of choice already and I sense that if there's a way to get this functionality with PHP you will go for it. Splitting your application across multiple languages/frameworks for one feature doesn't sound like the best of ideas.

Your main concern appears to be polling. Specifically: 2500 users long-polling at the same time. The most obvious way out is for you to adopt [HTML5 WebSockets](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSocket). Libraries exist to implement this in PHP such as [Ratchet](http://socketo.me/). Each user will have a constant connection to your central server using a websocket. Over this connection, each client can both send and receive data to and from the server. The server, being the intermediary step in this chain, can do whatever it wishes with the data as it passes data from one client to another, including storing it.

you may wonder how this is more scalable than long-polling. There is a great article on the **huge** performance improvements [right here](http://www.websocket.org/quantum.html). It boils down to websockets only sending data when an event has actually happened, instead of continuous "polls."